# SwiftUI DatePicker CompactDatePickerSyle accent color

Tags: swiftui, colors, datepicker, styles

It seems like setting the accent color is not working when the style of a DatePicker is set to CompactDatePickerStyle. It works as expected when using GraphicalDatePickerStyle.[image: Compact][image: Graphical]

Here's the code I'm using

```
DatePicker("Start Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                        .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
                        .accentColor(.red)
                        .padding()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, You will need to add the accent color in your Assets folder for it to show up. Second, the color will show only when you run the simulator or external it will not work in the preiview. Looks like it's a bug that needs to be reported...

[image: Accent Color]

[image]

Comment: Is this not just setting the accent color system wide?
What if you want to change the color of just the compact date label.